# How can I update Firefox add-ons automatically?

Tags: firefox, command-line, browser-addons, updates, yslow

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105766/how-to-disable-firefox-add-ons-update-check-on-start), is it possible to update installed plugins via the command line?

I'm running YSlow with beacon reporting as a nightly cron job under OSX:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -P YSlow http://www.example.com/ &
PID=$!
sleep 300
kill $PID
```

This dumps FF into the background and grabs the PID, waits 300 seconds (for the page to load) then kills it. If there is an update pending, the browser "hangs" waiting for a confirmation.

If I do click on the "install updates" link, everything works and then Firefox launches a new process - the **$!** returned by the shell is no longer valid.

Can I update a plugin from the command line without confirmation? Can I curl the XPI into a file and install it without confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following two changes are made to your **YSlow profile** in about:config:

```
app.update.mode=1;
app.update.silent=true;
```

`app.update.mode=1` will download updates automatically for major and minor releases. If there is a incompatibility addon issue, it will prompt. However in combination with `app.update.silent=true`, the incompatibility prompt will not display and the update will be ignore, effectively making the whole process silent.

Comment: It looks like these settings are for FF itself, I still have to update manually for extensions.